# Server and ServerSocket in one Application: not working

Tags: java, sockets, client, serversocket

I am trying to write a small program, that opens a server, creates a client that connects to this server and receives a message from it.

This is the Code so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
final ServerSocket serverSocket;
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
                try {
                    Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
                    writer.write("Hello World");
                    writer.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String message = reader.readLine();

        System.out.println("Received " + message);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

If i run program it keeps waiting in readLine() - so obviously the client does not receive the message from the server.
Has anyone got an idea why this isn' working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reading thread is waiting for a newline in the data stream. Just change the server to use:

```
writer.write("Hello World\r\n");
```

and you'll get the result you were expecting. Alternatively, you can just close the server socket, and then `readLine` will return when it reaches the end of the data stream.

Comment: Better: change `writer.write("Hello World");` to `writer.println("Hello World");`

Comment: @RyanStewart: Possibly. I personally prefer to make the code less dependent on the platform default - when it comes to network protocols, it shouldn't matter whether the server happens to be running Windows or some flavour of Unix.

Comment: True, though I suspect your option wouldn't work out so well on a Mac. If we're concerned about production-worthiness, the answer is to not use `reader.readLine()` for these exact reasons. That takes this example in a whole different direction, though.

Comment: @RyanStewart: It should do - `BufferedReader.readLine` deliberately copes with *all* of `\n`, `\r\n` and `\r` I believe. (Just checked: "Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.")

Comment: [True](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29). I didn't realize that.

Comment: OTOH you shouldn't use PrintWriter or PrintStream over a network, as they swallow exceptions.

Comment: @EJP: Yes, heartily agreed there. And it's using the platform default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the readline in a loop as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ServerSocket serverSocket;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
                    writer.write("Hello World");
                    writer.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            // Check this --------------------------------------------------->
            String message = null;
            while ((message = in.readLine()) != null) {   
                    System.out.println("Received " + message);
                    break; //This break will exit the loop when the first message is sent by the server
            }

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

You can read this documentation for further explanation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: That doesn't actually deal with the problem at all.